# How to Set Area Selection in TFS Using API

Tags: tfs

Creating an area within a project in TFS 2015. Once the area is added, no work-items in that area are showing up in the team's backlog. I realized that it is because, by default, the area is not selected, in this case *testarea* is un-selected.

[image: testArea is not selected]

Here's how I've created the area so far:

```
/*
 * Grabs the necessary connections to the server, as well as the required 
 * clients
 */
static void loadFromServer()
{
    // Connect to TFS
    VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), 
    new VssCredentials());

    // Get the project collection that the project is a part of
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri
    (collectionUri));

    // Get the version control server from the team project collection
    VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    string projectName = "SomeProject";

    // Get the project from the version control server
    static TeamProject project = vcs.GetTeamProject(projectName);

    // Get the ICommonStructureService to create the area
    static ICommonStructureService commonStructures = 
    tpc.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();
}

/*
 * Create the new area
 */
static void createArea()
{
    // Root area of the project
    NodeInfo rootAreaNode = commonStructures.GetNodeFromPath(projectName 
    + "\\Area");

    string areaName = "SomeArea";
    // Create the new area node
    string newAreaUri = commonStructures.CreateNode(areaName, 
    rootAreaNode.Uri);

    Console.WriteLine(areaName + " created.");
}
```

How would I go about selecting the new area that I've created, so that it displays a check-mark in the check-box to the left of it, allowing my team to view work-items in the backlog for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, we can not select the area with API. I have submitted a [**user voice here**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31056052-rest-api-to-select-area) to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve it in feature.

According to the official documents [Work item classification nodes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/classification-nodes#create-an-area), there isn't the REST API to select/update the area data. We can only [Move an area node](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/classification-nodes#move-an-area-node).

However, with the [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) tool to track the select area action, we can get the API which is invoked when select the area. To do the post action, it needs a token, but the token is dynamic. So, we cannot invoke the API with static token to update the area data (select the area).

[image]